# HTTP to HTTPS redirection doesn't work when there is only one page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This well known code to redirect from the `http://` to the `https://` version of the URL doesn't work when there is only a single `index.php` file in the root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Indeed I get a `Too many redirects` error: any help, please?

EDIT: for the sake of completeness, to esclude other rules, I'm using [the HTML5Boilerplate template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/master/dist/.htaccess) as-is. Anyway, after first fail, I copied it from top to bottom in pieces: it is all fine but when I copy that *http to https* rule, where I get the `Too many redirects` error

Comment: The condition looks fine. Maybe there are other rules causing additional redirects.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, I added some more information about other rules (I'm using the HTML5Boilpleate template without modifying it)